HYBRIDNETS Tflite output format
I found a HYBRIDNETS model for segmentation with tflite extension but I don't know how to use it on kotlin.
I started like this but I don't know the output format of this. Can you help me?
private var interpreter: Interpreter

private val inputTensorProcessor = ImageProcessor.Builder()
    .add(ResizeOp(512, 640, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))
    .add(NormalizeOp(NORM_MEAN, NORM_STD))
    .build()

init {
    // Initialize TFLite Interpreter
    val interpreterOptions = Interpreter.Options().apply {
        // Use GPU acceleration if available.
        // See -> https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/performance/gpu#android
        val compatibilityList = CompatibilityList()
        //if (compatibilityList.isDelegateSupportedOnThisDevice) {
        this.addDelegate(org.tensorflow.lite.gpu.GpuDelegate(compatibilityList.bestOptionsForThisDevice))
        //}
        this.numThreads = NUM_THREADS
    }
    interpreter = Interpreter(
        FileUtil.loadMappedFile(MainActivity.applicationContext(), MODEL_NAME),
        interpreterOptions
    )
}

fun getResuls(inputImage: Bitmap) {
    val resizedBit = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inputImage, 640, 512, true)

    var inputTensor = TensorImage.fromBitmap(resizedBit)

    val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

    inputTensor = inputTensorProcessor.process(inputTensor)
}

